# Thymeleaf parse exeption when writing unknown expression syntax inside tag property

Tags: kotlin, thymeleaf

I want to save thymeleaf with php script inside the tag attribute property and get it to execute with php server later. But I cannot save it. Please help me,
Can we do something to allow thymeleaf accept it?

My code sample:

```
<div class="text-center" th:if="<?php echo 'true'; ?>"> I am in danger </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you want to do? You can't expect Thymeleaf to be able to execute PHP code.

Comment: Yep, this just isn't going to work. The value in a `th:if` field needs to be both valid xml (can't use `>` or `<` without escaping them) and a valid OGNL/SPeL expression of which  `<?php echo 'true'; ?>` is not... so not sure what exactly you want here...

Comment: Excuse me, Sir  Wim Deblauwe and Metroids:
- In my case, I want to execute php first before allow thymeleaf to render.
- I have php environment that can execute. I may send this Tag
  <div class="text-center" th:if="<?php echo 'true'; ?>"> I am in danger </div>
to php server first then thymeleaf will render but I cannot save it.
- I just want to save and vaildate it as a thymeleaf.